# Как получить дочернюю директорию через cmd заменить подстроку в файле в цикле?

Tags: windows, cmd

Есть папка с подпапками:

```
---main
   --- ru
      --- dir
          ---index.html
```

Следующий скрипт (geo.cmd) копирует директории RU и переименовывает нужные (ag, am и т.д.):

```
@echo off
chcp 65001
for %%l in (ag am) do (
    xcopy /E /I /Q /Y ru %%l
)
```

Мне нужно в цикле переименовать файл index.html в index_ag.html, index_am.html и так далее.
Для этого использую строку - `ren %%l\dir\index.html index_%%l.html`

```
@echo off
chcp 65001
for %%l in (ag am) do (
    xcopy /E /I /Q /Y ru %%l
    ren %%l\dir\index.html index_%%l.html
)
```

Но проблема в том, что папка `dir` может называться по разному. Поэтому мне нужно получить название дочерней папки (dir), и уже потом переименовывать файл. Как мне можно получить название дочерней папки? Пытаюсь использовать команду dir, но не могу понять, как получить дочернюю папку.

Также в каждом файле index.html нужно заменить строку `<html lang="ru">` на строки `<html lang="en">` для AG и `<html lang="hy">` для AM. Какая команда используется для замены текста?

Comment: Тут принято отмечать ответы, которые помогли.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы узнать имя папки `dir`:

```
for /f %%x in ('dir /ad /b main\ru') do @set dir_name=%%x
echo %dir_name%
```

Чтобы заменить строку в файле, нужен нормальный скриптовый язык, а не тупая запускалка файлов, которой является `cmd`